# Thymeleaf - Validation on collection of object

Tags: javascript, java, spring, validation, thymeleaf

I am using thymeleaf to display my website. It is a form with listed inputs.

```
<tr th:each="entry, stat : ${formWrapper.propertiesList}">
    <td> <label class="propertiesLabel" th:text="${entry.key}"/></label></td>
    <td> <input type="text" th:id="${entry.key}" th:field="*{propertiesList[__${stat.index}__].value}"></input></td>
</tr>
```

In my model, my form contains of this objects.

```
public form(String key, String value){
    super();
    this.key = key;
    this.value = value;
}

//getter amd setter methods
```

I also have a wrapper to wrap the form.

```
public ArrayList<Form> getPropertiesList(){
    return propertiesList;
}

public void setPropertiesList(ArrayList<Form> properties){
    this.propertiesList = properties;
}
```

Anybody have any methods to validate the list of input values? Either through javascript(Front-End) or Java(Back-end) is good to me.

Answer (score 0):

You can use hibernate validator to validate `Form` in the backend. All you need to do it annotate the properties of `Form` with whatever validations you need. The `@NotNull` annotation verifies key and value is not null. If it happens to be null, it will return the message associated with it. The `@Size` annotation verifies the maximum size of key and value is 20 and 30 respectively. If it happens to be more than the specified limit, the message associated with it will be returned.

```
public class Form {
    @NotNull(message = "Key cannot be null")
    @Size(max = 20,message = "Maximum size is 20")
    private String key;
    @NotNull(message = "value cannot be null")
    @Size(max = 30,message = "Maximum size is 30")
    private String value;

    //getters and setters
}
```

Then you can check the validity in the handler function like

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/saveForm",method = RequestMethod.POST)
public void saveForm(@Valid Form form,BindingResult bindingResult){        
    if(bindingResult.hasErrors()){            
        // bindingResult.getAllErrors() gets you all the errors. Now handle it
    }        
}
```

Comment: Hi @Vyshak, thanks for the answer. If every value in the input needs to be validated differently, for example: input A is text only, input B is integer only and so on... Can it still be done?

Comment: @Ken.T Yes it can be done. For example if input B is integer only you can use @Pattern(regexp = "\\d+",message = "Only numbers are allowed"). Same can be done for input A. Just use the appropriate regex.